# Decrypt TLS and/or compare TLS payloads

Tags: ssl, encryption, compare, ssl-certificate

#### Problem:

I'm pretty new to this TLS thing and networking in general. But i'm trying to passively listen and decode TLS packets. I find it kind of frustrating that i cant decode packets on my network on my computer. The conclusion i got to is that is impossible because how TLS works. But in mathematics if you have enough of information you can often get the value of the unknown. In this instance i guess it might be the servers key that is the missing link.

Even if it would be cool to totally decrypt packets its not my main goal. What i specifically trying to do is to know if a specific twitch stream is watched on my computer/network. So if i type in the streamers name in to the program it checks if that stream is sent to my computer and responds with a boolean.

So i want your input guys and girls. Is there any way of achieve this without doing Man in the middle?

#### Thoughts:

I have been thinking about this problem and i got a couple of ideas (don't laugh at the possible stupidity, I'm not always very smart but its just some things that came to my mind):

1. **(Comparing)** Using my cert to send request to the twitch api and somehow compare the response and see if they have the same encrypted payload. Then i know this specific stream is watched.
2. **(Decoding)** feed cert (public and private key), decrypted message and encrypted message to some algorithm to get server key. My theory here is that i have enough information to get the server key. But my knowledge about ssl is limited and i have not considered handshakes and such.
3. **(Decoding)** Generate training data to an ai to teach it to decode ssl packets. Generating a lot of ssl packets with different keys and feed the cert and encrypted data to the ai.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. English is not my native language (sorry).

Comment: This is not a programming question, so offtopic here. I recommend you first read some tutorials on TLS. You will then see that what you want to do is exactly what TLS has been build to defend against so, no, you can not compare or decrypt things the way you think (if everything is implemented and used correctly of course). The last case is more or less called an Oracle, this exists to exploit some SSL/TLS vulnerabilities in specific cases.

Comment: "I find it kind of frustrating that i cant decode packets on my network on my computer." I do not understand this. If packets come from your computer, from an application you control then content is encrypted in transit, but is obviously in clear in your application, so if you control it, you see all traffic in any way you want. Otherwise indeed you need either an intercepting proxy and be able to trick applications into accepting any certificate or your application must give you the client random and master secret used for the exchange in order to decrypt traffic sniffed passively.

Comment: "But in mathematics if you have enough of information you can often get the value of the unknown." What works in mathematics may break in real life. Take for example hashing functions, we say they do not collide but they mathematically obviously do since the outgoing space is finite. Same for keys. You can try to brute force them. Mathematically you know you will succeed at some point... but practically, say for a 2048 bits key, try to see amount of time and energy needed to brute force it (test all possible combinations) and will see you hit a problem.

Comment: In short, if you want "if a specific twitch stream is watched on my computer/network." that is any kind of level 7 or higher policing, you need DPI that is inspect content of packets. Which means an intercepting proxy for TLS stuff and even then understand the specific protocol used inside (if it is HTTP it is easy, if it is a proprietary protocol, what you will do?). So your problem is really not "breaking TLS" but more "policing your users" and establishing rules on what happens on your network.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Can you clarify what you mean by level 7 policing?

Comment: Level 7 in the OSI stack or level 5 in Internet stack if you prefer, see this for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite.  Basically this is the specific application data for the specific protocol you study. It could be a standard one, like HTTP, or some proprietary one. It means you want to filter things not only/primarily based on IP addresses or TCP ports, but really by looking into what is exchanged, the specific protocol data (which may be encrypted by TLS, indeed).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek technically i don't need to see the content i just need to compare if they have the same content.

Comment: Again, does not work like that (otherwise it would be too easy to break TLS, you just enumerate all possible content in advance, encrypt it, and compare to encrypted content and if it matches you know what it was un-encrypted), you can not just compare the encrypted data, each connection uses different ephemeral keys, the same content will get encrypted differently each time...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I see. So even if i use same certificate, same ip to the same ip with the same request i still wont get the same encrypted message?

Comment: Yes. This is TLS 101 and written in the first lines of the wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security : *The keys for this symmetric encryption are generated uniquely for each connection and are based on a shared secret negotiated at the start of the session*. Please take time to read it, I am sure you will find many answers to your questions.

Comment: 1. Can't work. 2. Possible. 3. That will never work.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. (Comparing) Using my cert to send request to the twitch api and somehow compare the response and see if they have the same encrypted payload. Then i know this specific stream is watched.

Data are encrypted with a symmetric key specific for this SSL/TLS session. Also a random initialization vector is used. Thus, even transfer of exactly the same data results in different encrypted data which means no comparison of the encrypted data will help.

> 2. (Decoding) feed cert (public and private key), decrypted message and encrypted message to some algorithm to get server key. My theory here is that i have enough information to get the server key. But my knowledge about ssl is limited and i have not considered handshakes and such.

If (the obsolete) RSA key exchange is used you would need to have the servers private key to decrypt which you don't have. With Diffie-Hellman key exchange even this private key would not be sufficient, but you need to have the master secret or pre-master secret of this specific SSL/TLS session (see the TLS standards for details what this is). This secret can only be found in the TLS client and TLS server for the time the TLS session is active - which means that you will not be able to use this either for decryption unless you have access to the internals of the client, in which case you might just look directly which stream they are viewing.

> 3. (Decoding) Generate training data to an ai to teach it to decode ssl packets. Generating a lot of ssl packets with different keys and feed the cert and encrypted data to the ai.

Properly encrypted data are more or less random and have no inherent structure which can be mapped to the original data or even parts of the data. AI will not magically find such a structure too. The only possible difference it might use to distinguish streams are the size and timing of the data - but only if these are specific for a stream which I doubt. So, most likely it is impossible this way too.

Comment: So it is impossible? I find it quite amazing that you can have so much information and still not be able to decrypt it.

Comment: @objectnabb: Given that your internet provider or mobile provider can easily sniff all these information too I rather find it comforting that it is not possible to easily decrypt the data. But that's modern cryptography - properly used it can really protect you from others, and others from you.

Comment: Yes i agree with you. It would be a problem. I'll contact genua GmbH if i succeed ;)

Comment: "that you can have so much information and still not be able to decrypt it." that is exactly the purpose of good encryption algorithm: make the output look like completely random which means no conclusions could be drawn by analyzing just it (without any other clue). This succeeds more or less depending on the algorithms or their various implementations flaws. Studying past vulnerabilities is also a good way to better understand TLS, what it protects against and how it does it.

Comment: PS: TLS 1.3 just went out one week ago.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I will definitively look in to that thanks. I'm getting more and more curious about this. This is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> I find it kind of frustrating that i cant decode packets on my network on my computer. The conclusion i got to is that is impossible because how TLS works.

Indeed this is primary purpose of TLS. If correctly implemented you should have no way of decrypting transfered data.

There are even buggy and obsolete implementation on some servers where one can exploit some vulnerabilities, but - not for Twitch <del>and not with your knowledge level</del> only for buggy implementation

Generally you could consider TLS secure enough to ensure  traffic integrity and confidentiality.

> What i specifically trying to do is to know if a specific twitch stream is watched on my computer/network.

I'd provide some options to achieve the goal, however that would introduce dangerous vulnerabilities into your computer or network. (you have been warned)

- Still you can sniff out the unencrypted traffic. So you can see e. g. DNS requests (you could see what hostnames are resolved, but not specific URL).
- For your computer you could install a keylogger or get the requested URL from browser before it is encrypted.
- Integrity of TLS rely on certification authorities. In theory could can create your own CA certificate and make it trusted on your computer or network. That could allow you mounting a man-in-the-middle attack (posing yourself as the target server with your own keys).

Comment: Even DNS can be encrypted with DNS over HTTPS and DNS over TLS.

Comment: @gusto2 "not with your knowledge level" My main goal is to learn. I have no CS degree no formal education in computer programming. I want to clarify that i have read up on Diffie–Hellman key exchange and such. But some stuff is hard to grasp without going very deep into the rabbit hole. I'm asking all of this because i don't want to start in the wrong end, i do after all have a goal even though it's mainly for learning purpose. (I know you probably did not want to be rude).

Comment: @objectnabb I did not mean to be rude. I'm trying to say - sometimes vulnerabilities are found (e.g. try to search for heartblead) and it may happen that there is a small window of opportunity to exploit the vulnerability before it is fixed (good sites fixes these things very quickly). This case is rather over wrong imlementation than decrypting TLS traffic itself and this kind of hacks require close follow of the TLS implementations. In short - it is virtually impossible to decrypt TLS and you may rather try to find another way to achieve your goal

Comment: @Patrick-Mevzek indeed. DNS over TLS is not yet so common that it should, but IMHO it will be

Comment: I wish so, but unfortunately the "market" will probably favor DNS overt HTTPS  instead (for its roadblock avoidance feature) and the path is already started, as newer versions of Firefox already do DNS over HTTPS by default.

Comment: @gusto2 About Diffie-Hellman, have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBfamv-_do  it explains it by using colors, no mathematical background needed, can be a good introduction.

Comment: @Patrick-Mevzek the goal of the guy was finding if a specific stream/url was requested and he wants to achieve that by decrypting TLS . IMHO the TLS is secure enough (there is no know way to break https when implemented properly) , so he should try to achieve the goal different way.